# Dialogflow authentication API v2 - HTTP POST

Tags: google-apps-script, twilio, google-oauth, dialogflow-es, http-status-code-401

I´m using dialogflow with http request on a project that works in twilio, with the recent need of migration to v2 API of dialogflow the client access token will not work. Reading the new authentication, I generated the json following the instructions in the google cloud docs, but can´t make it works. Because I need to do all the interaction through POST requests to the dialogflow agent, does anyone know how I can generate the authentication token well?

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
        "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Show your code. See [mcve]

Comment: Use a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts) and if you are using NodeJs check [Google Auth Service Account Tokens for Node.js](https://github.com/googleapis/node-gtoken)

Comment: I arleady configure service account but the module google-auth can't be used in twilio functions, another way to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

This is the function code that today works to make the http request. The problem is that all the services are in Twilio and i dont have access to the server, for that I cant define the environment variable.

[Twilio Function code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNaCt.png)

Twilio Fuctions uses NodeJs and allow me to install many npm modules, with the following limitation: "Native Packages Not Supported - Functions does not provide a C/C++ compliler required to complie native addon modules. This means modules that depend on node-gyp can not be installed to Functions."

I don´t know if this limitations affect service acount working to me in this case.